# Check if there is a new release on github for game

Tags: java, github

I'm making a game in java with a friend I would like to know how to check when the game starts up if there is a new version available for download on our GitHub repository. Anyway this is possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the REST API to github.com. [Here is a link](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/) to the official documentation for working with releases. You will want to invoke:

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/releases
```

You will need to read the documentation to learn how to connect, authenticate, and get into the correct context.